# what will be the SQL query for this operation for travels management?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following relationship model:

- travel (id_travel, date, departure_city, arrival_city, nb_places, ...)
- step (id_step, step_city, id_travel#)

On the other hand, I have a search form where the user must enter the city of departure and the city of arrival. When he clicks on search, I must retrieve database travels that meet the following criteria:

- Same departure city (user input and travel.departure_city) and same arrival  city (user input and travel.arrival_city);
- The departure city entered by the user (input user) is a step in the travel (step_city) and same city of arrival (user input and travel.arrival_city);
- Same departure city (user input and travel.departure_city) and arrival city entered by the user (input user) is a step in the travel (step.step_city);
- The departure (input user) and arrival input user cities entered by the user are steps in the travel (step.step_city).

Example:
Suppose that in the database I have the travel from City A to City B and passing through City C and City D. This travel must be included in the user's searches in the following cases:

- Departure: City A and Arrival: City B;
- Departure: City C or D and Arrival: City B;
- Departure: City A and Arrival: City C or D;
- Departure: City C and Arrival: City D;

is there an SQL query to perform this operation?

Comment: Please tag your table with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results also help.

Comment: what have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: I'm using php/mysql for my application.

Comment: I want to retreive by a form, with one query, all travels that meet one of the 4 criteria in the question.